# Declaring namespace in main file doesn't carry over to header files: "using namespace std;"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, namespaces

My professor has provided my class with a single .cpp file containing my main function, as well as three header files for three different Classes. In the main file, he utilizes "using namespace std;" to declare the namespace for the project.

I'm aware that "using namespace std;" is bad practice and should be avoided at all costs, but the teacher insists on three important points in the completion of the project:

1. **You must not modify any of the provided files. "Not a single character". (60% reduction in marks)**
2. It fails to build in Visual Studio 2017. (60% reduction in marks)
3. It crashes during normal operation. (60% reduction in marks)

My problem is that the namespace declared in the main file (via the use of "using namespace std;"), doesn't appear to be carrying over to the header files.

Here is the main file:

```
// ass2.cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC   // need this to get the line identification
//_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF); // in main, after local declarations
//NB must be in debug build
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std; // THE NAMESPACE DECLARATION
#include "Frame.h"
#include "Animation.h"
#include "AnimationManager.h"

int main(void)
{
    char response;
    bool RUNNING = true;
    AnimationManager M("Manager1");
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    while (RUNNING)
    {
        cout << "MENU\n 1. Add an Animation\n 2. Delete an Animation\n 3. Edit an Animation\n 4. list the Animations\n 5. Quit" << endl;
        cin >> response;
        switch (response)
        {
        case '1':cin >> M; break;
        case '2':M.DeleteAnimation(); break;
        case '3':M.EditAnimation(); break;
        case '4':cout << M; break;
        case '5':RUNNING = false; break;
        default:cout << "Please enter a valid option" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's one of the header files, the rest are the same in their construction:

```
//Animation.h
#pragma once

class Animation
{
    string animationName;
    forward_list<Frame> frames;
public:
    Animation(string name) :animationName(name) {}
    ~Animation() {}
    void EditFrame();
    void DeleteFrame();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Animation&);// Add a Frame as in cin >> A;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Animation&);// output the Frames as in cout << A;
};
```

I created a test file which recreates the occurence, the `using namespace std;` statement was placed before the `#include "xxx.h"` statements.

Main file for the test space that I created:

```
//: C12:IostreamOperatorOverloading.cpp
// Modified
// From Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition
// Available at http://www.BruceEckel.com
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// Copyright notice in Copyright.txt
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC   // need this to get the line identification
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
using namespace std;
#include "IntArray.h"

    int main() {
        char q;
        IntArray I, J;
        _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
        cout << "Overloaded extraction" << endl;
        cin >> I;
        cout << "Overloaded insertion" << endl;
        cout << I;
        cout << "Chained extraction" << endl;
        cin >> I >> J;
        cout << "Chained Insertion" << endl;
        cout << I << J;
        cout << "***********overloaded operator[] - returns an l-value*************" << endl << endl;
        I[4] = -1;
        J[0] = 99;
        cout << I << J;
        cout << "*******a returned r-value assigned to a returned l-value************" << endl << endl;
        I[0] = I[4];
        J[0] = I[1] = J[2];     // chained indexing
        cout << I << J;
        cout << endl << "********or, using explicit function calls (never do it this way) ********" << endl;
        operator>>(operator>>(cin, I), J);  //  cin >> I >> J;
        operator<<(operator<<(cout, I), J); //  cout << I <<  J;
        cout << "**************************************************" << endl;
        I.operator[](4) = -1;   // I[4] = -1;
        J.operator[](0) = 99;   // J[0] = 99;
        operator<<(operator<<(cout, I), J); // cout << I <<  J;
        cout << "**************************************************" << endl;
        I.operator[](0) = I.operator[](4);  // a returned r-value assigned to a returned l-value
        J.operator[](0) = I.operator[](1) = J.operator[](2);    // chained indexing
        operator<<(operator<<(cout, I), J);
        cout << "**************************************************" << endl;

        cin >> q;
    } ///:~
```

Header file for the test space that I created:

```
#pragma once

class IntArray {

    enum { sz = 5 };
    int i[sz];

public:

    IntArray() { memset(i, 0, sz * sizeof(*i)); }

    // Overloaded indexing operator
    int& operator[](int x) {
        return i[x];
    }

    // non-member friend overloaded operators - global functions
    // a friend has access to the private members of the class
    friend ostream&  operator<<(ostream& os, IntArray& ia); // overloaded insertion operator global function
    friend istream&  operator>>(istream& is, IntArray& ia); // overloaded extraction operator global function
};
```

.cpp file for the test space that I created, containing the definitions for the IntArray Class functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntArray.h"
using namespace std;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, IntArray& ia) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ia.sz; j++) {
        //    os << ia.i[j];    // OK, this is the primitive way.
        os << ia[j];        // Better, now we have overloaded indexing.
        if (j != ia.sz - 1)
            os << ", ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, IntArray& ia) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ia.sz; j++)
        //   is >> ia.i[j]; // OK, this is the primitive way.
        is >> ia[j];        // Better, now we have overloaded indexing.
    return is;
}
```

And finally, here's a sample of the errors being spat in my face from the test file which recreates the occurrence:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PTR, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>IntArray.cpp
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(19): error C2433: 'ostream': 'friend' not permitted on data declarations
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(19): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(20): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(20): error C2433: 'istream': 'friend' not permitted on data declarations
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(20): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.cpp(6): error C2248: 'IntArray::sz': cannot access private enumerator declared in class 'IntArray'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(5): note: see declaration of 'IntArray::sz'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(3): note: see declaration of 'IntArray'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.cpp(9): error C2248: 'IntArray::sz': cannot access private enumerator declared in class 'IntArray'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(5): note: see declaration of 'IntArray::sz'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(3): note: see declaration of 'IntArray'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.cpp(17): error C2248: 'IntArray::sz': cannot access private enumerator declared in class 'IntArray'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(5): note: see declaration of 'IntArray::sz'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\ptr\ptr\intarray.h(3): note: see declaration of 'IntArray'
1>Done building project "PTR.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I found that by adding the "using namespace std;" statement at the top of the header files (Which is VERY BAD practice) solves the issue, but that would cost me 60% of the assignment marks as it violates the first of his three important points.

I would greatly appreciate help with solving this. I have been reading about the issue for the past few hours, but this appears to be (to me) a very peculiar case... Thank you all!

Comment: In the professor's file, the `using namespace std;` is before the `#include`.  If you do this in your own .cpp files, the problem will probably disappear.  This is, as you already know, a terrible idea -- but the restrictions on the question don't let you use a better method.

Comment: If your professor impose such restrictions, he should, at least, writing using best practices

Comment: I know right @Amadeus. Namespaces are bad when you use it like that

Comment: @BenVoigt After creating a new project and doing as you suggested (creating my own .cpp files), the problem persists. The error messages that I posted were from a newly created project with the "using namespace std;" statement placed before the include statements. I will edit the question to make it clearer - Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Amadeus I agree entirely! Why he uses statements that are so badly regarded when teaching the "next generation of computer scientists" (his words) is beyond me.

Comment: This is the second question I read today on stackoverflow.com that includes evidence of an incompetent instructor. I simultaneously feel sad for the unfortunate souls that have to deal with these situations, and happy for having perpetual job security, until I croak.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hi Ben, the question has been updated with the build output, instead of output from the error list.

Comment: You should show what you have done. See a list of error without accessing the source is cumbersome

Comment: So the build error reference some file named  `intarray.h`, which is not even shown in the question. Claims that " the rest are the same in their construction" don't really help much. This is like me claiming that my Honda is broken, showing someone a picture of my Toyota, and then ask what the problem might be (the Honda looks basically the same).

Comment: @Amadeus Question updated with all source code from the test space that I created.

Comment: @BenVoigt Question updated with all source code from the test space that I created.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Question updated with all source code from the test space that I created.

Comment: And your intarray.cpp file is not doing what I suggested in my very first comment :(

Comment: @BenVoigt Holy crap, I misunderstood... Forgive me for my insolence and idiocy; This solved the problem... Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck maintaining your sanity in this class with the insane grading rules.  For the future, the best practice is actually for the very first line of whatever.cpp to be `#include "whatever.h"` -- but you sadly won't be able to follow that with this professor.

Comment: In source files that include those headers, place a using directive (`using namespace std`) before including the headers.   Yes, it's poor practice for header files to rely on that, but the constraints you describe mean you don't have much choice.

Comment: Personally, I would take the grade reduction by fixing the code properly, and then put a huge comment in the code explaining the situation and pointing out the teacher's mistake of providing wrong code to pretty much guarantee bad results from students. Teachers are human, too. If he doesn't like it, I would drop the class and find a more competent teacher.